# What is u:R d:R that appears on ERD when adding relationship (Visio 2010)

Tags: microsoft-visio, erd

I am building a Entity-Relationship diagram in Vision 2010 using crow's feet. Everytime I connect to tables with a relationship the following element appears near the "many" side.

u:R
d:R

I can click on the element and delete it but would like to know what it is used for, obviously it has to do with Relationship.

Comment: A screenshot might help loads here

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: See below.

Comment: ahh right. I wasn't asked to do that on my database course, and I sort of ended up using another tool, which probably explains my unfamiliarity with it ;p

Answer (score 3):

Example:

[image: 1]

The notation represents **U**pdate and **D**elete operations enforced by [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) rules.

If a Primary Key (PK) is linked to a Foreign Key (FK) in another table, we need to ensure that referential integrity is maintained. Depending on what makes business sense, the update rule can be either:

- U:R (Update:Restrict) – Disallow updates of values in the PK
- U:C (Update:Cascade) – Allow updates, but cascade changes to all related FKs in other tables

Similarly, the delete rule can be either:

- D:R (Delete:Restrict) – Disallow deletion of records
- D:C (Delete:Cascade) – Allow deletion of records, but cascade deletions in all related tables that contain a FK linked to this table

Notations available in Visio are:

- R (No action) - Don't change the child table
- C (Cascade) - Replicate the change in the child table
- D (Set default) - Insert the default value you previously set for that column in the child table
- N (Set Null) - Set the child table to NULL
- (Blank) - Do not enforce referential integrity on the relationship

See the [Preserve referential integrity in Database Model diagrams](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/visio-help/preserve-referential-integrity-in-database-model-diagrams-HA010115483.aspx) article for more details.